# lightbox is not working in updatepanel c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

A $ function (which is a DOM ready function) will be only be executed when the page loads for the first time. Any further AJAX call (which is a partial loading/rendering) will not fire DOM ready function. Which is the reason, I were not able to get it working.

In you case, this function binds my anchor link (button) with the lighbox behavior the first time the page loads. so, it works. The next time when I refresh the update panel (which is a partial render) the button is not bound to lightbox again. Unless this binding is achieved it will not show up.

it work fine first time when page is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').flipLightBox();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call Javascript/jQuery function in an `UpdatePanel` you need place them inside the `pageLoad()` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
         $('body').flipLightBox();
    }
</script>
```

This will call it on every update of the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Show me Error: TypeError: $(...).flipLightBox is not a function

Comment: @MohanKumar If the code you provided in the question works, this should work either.

Comment: the first time works. The next time when I refresh the update panel then code is not work. throw error $(...).flipLightBox  is not a function.

Comment: @MohanKumar that's strange I always use it. Check the plugin you are using.